# Pass a date into an sqlplus command from within a bash script

Tags: bash, variables, plsql, sqlplus

I have the following bash script which is supposed to call sqlplus with the current date.

```
#!/bin/bash

DATE='date +%F'

sqlplus -s << EOF1
DB_username/DB_password
set heading off
exec PLSQL_PROCEDURE('$DATE', '-30','someString','/home/outputFolder');
exit
EOF1

exit
```

I get the following error however- it's definitely not evaluating the date command:

```
BEGIN PLSQL_PROCEDURE('date +%F', '-30', 'someString', '/home/outputFolder'); END;

*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01841: (full) year must be between -4713 and +9999, and not be 0
ORA-06512: at "DataBaseName.PLSQL_PROCEDURE", line 19
ORA-06512: at line 1
```

How can I fix it so that it passes the current date in, like this?

```
PLSQL_PROCEDURE('2013-03-14', '-30', 'someString', '/home/outputFolder');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead :

```
#!/bin/sh

DATE=$(date +%F) # note the $( ) form

sqlplus -s  << EOF1
DB_username/DB_password
set heading off
exec PLSQL_PROCEDURE('$DATE', '-30','someString','/home/outputFolder');
exit
EOF1
```

You should learn about *Command Substitution*: The `$(foo bar)` causes the command 'foo' to be executed with the argument 'bar' and `$(..)` will be replaced by the *output*. See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/002